# How to return a row twice inside map method

Tags: ruby

I would like to return a value twice inside a map method, only if (for example) the `key == :b`

I have something like this:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.map{ |x| x }
# => [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 3]]
```

I would like to create this:

```
# => [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:b, 2], [:c, 3]]
```

I tried:

```
output = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.map{ |x| x.first == :b ? [x,x] : x }
# => [[:a, 1], [[:b, 2], [:b, 2]], [:c, 3]]

output.flatten
# => [:a, 1, :b, 2, :b, 2, :c, 3]
output.flatten(1)
# => [:a, 1, [:b, 2], [:b, 2], :c, 3]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.map{ |x| x.first == :b ? [x,x] : [x] }.flatten(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write it in a single line 
`{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.map{ |x| x.first == :b ? [x,x] : [x] }.flatten(1)`

Comment: Oh, so simple xD. I knew I was close. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.map{ |x| x.first == :b ? [x,x] : [x] }.flatten(1)
```

or

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.reduce([]){ |memo, x| x.first == :b ? memo << x << x : memo << x }
```

or maybe a couple dozen other ways :)